# Unity WebGL disable cookies or how to update game objects from url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cookies, unity-webgl

I've implemented script that creates elements from url xml file using `UnityWebRequest.Get(uri)`.
But this file can be changed in runtime, so I am trying to update the model, by uploading same xml file, but seems it stored in cookies and model can't be update. It work only when i delete history and delete cookies, in this way model can be updated. In play mode, it works fine, because there is no any local data storage. 
Is there any way clear cookies during update or disable cookies save or any other way to update model?

Comment: The webserver is responsible for this. It should set the `Cache-Control: no-cache` so the browser will re-request it. So check the headers serverside.

Comment: Found similar post:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/209078/disable-cache-for-www.html